# messy index in texlive 2015

Tags: indexing

I used the texlive for writing my book in persian (by using xepersian). For index I used xeindex package.
My index is very messy and the numbers are disoriented and the words are not in the determined frame as you can see in the picture.
How can I solve this?[image: my first page of index]